# cardinality of the power set, how calculate this

Tags: combinatorics

i have task.
what is the cardinality of the set:
{(A,B,C) $\in$ $P([n])^3$ : A = B $\cap$ C }, where $[n] = {1, 2,..., n}$?

Any ideas how solve this?

Comment: Surely the number of tuples $(B \cap C, B, C)$ is not more than of tuples $(B, C)$.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė "not more" ? the same, in fact.

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is determined from $B$ and $C$ so you just need the cardinality of a pair of sets.